# How to place the widgets close to close?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am facing the problem

If two widgets added in a column, there is space between the widgets . I need to remove the space between them. how to acheive it.

```
    Container(height: 50,
                width: 50,
                color: Colors.grey,
                child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    Flexible(flex: 2,
                        child: Container(color: Colors.indigo,
                            child: SizedBox(child: Icon(
                              Icons.filter_list, color: Colors.white,),))),            
                    Flexible( flex:1, child:
                  Text('5',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),)
                ),]));
```

The output should be

[image]

Actually i need this scenario also,

[image]

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can add a height of 0.6 to the text widget.

```
Container(
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    color: Colors.grey,
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          child: Text(
            '5',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: Text(
            '5',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, height: 0.6),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily overlap two widgets using [assorted_layout_widgets package](https://github.com/marcglasberg/assorted_layout_widgets) with `innerDistance` argument:

```
return ColumnSuper(
        innerDistance: -8,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '5',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.filter_list,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ]
      );
```

Comment: I need one text and after that icon.How to acheive it . There should be no space between text and icon

Comment: @rizwika I think I found the perfect solution for you, check the updated answer